# Eliminating $t$ from $x=k_1 \cos ^2 t + k_2 \sin^2 t$ and $y=(k_1-k_2)\sin t \cos t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How is simplification easily done to obtain its semi-circle equation from this parametrization?

$$\begin{align} x &=  k_1 \cos ^2 t + k_2 \sin^2 t\\
y&=(k_1-k_2)\sin t \cos t\end{align}$$

Comment: Rewrite $\cos^2t$ and $\sin^2t$ in terms of $\cos2t$, and $\sin t \cos t$ in terms of $\sin2t$. Substitute into $\cos^22t+\sin^22t=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that,
\begin{align}
 x= k_1 \cos^2{t} +k_2 \sin^2{t}     
   & = k_1+(k_2-k_1)\sin^2{t}\\ \end{align}
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow \ x-k_1= (k_2-k_1)\sin^2t
\qquad(1)
\end{align}
Again,

\begin{align}
 x= k_1 \cos^2{t} +k_2 \sin^2{t}     
   & = (k_1-k_2) \cos^2{t} + k_2\\ \end{align}
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow \ x-k_2= (k_1-k_2)\cos^2t
\qquad(2)
\end{align}

From $\ (1)×\ (2) $,

\begin{align}\
(k_1-x)(x-k_2)=(k_1-k_2)^2\ \cos^2t \ \sin^2{t} \qquad(3)\end{align}

Also given,
\begin{align}
y=(k_1-k_2)\ \cos t \ \sin {t} \end{align}
\begin{align}\Rightarrow
y^2=(k_1-k_2)^2\ \cos^2t \ \sin^2 {t} \qquad(4) \end{align}

Finally from $\ (3)÷\ (4) $,
\begin{align}
y^2=(k_1-x)(x-k_2)  \end{align}